# How to add line break in XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I have a script that generates XML data and saves it to file:

```
result_XML = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    ...
    xml.job {
      xml.job_id            job_id
      xml.job_description   job_description
    }
  }
end

File.open("result.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(result_XML.to_xml) }
```

In `job_description` I have text that can contain line-breaks ("\n"). I want them to be displayed when I open the resulting file, but when I open it all description is shown as one string without any breaks.

I tried `&#xD;`, `&#xA;`, `<[!CDATA[ ... ]]>`, but nothing works.

**Example:**

```
job_id = 109504
job_description = "Requirements:\n 1. Be polite.\n 2. 20+ years old."

result_XML = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.job {
      xml.job_id_            job_id
      xml.job_description_   job_description
    }
  }
end

File.open("result.xml", 'w') { |f| f.write(result_XML.to_xml) }
```

And now if I open file result.xml in browser I will get:

```
<root>
  <job>
    <job_id>109504</job_id>
    <job_description>Requirements: 1. Be polite. 2. 20+ years old.</job_description>
  </job>
</root>
```

And an error that there is no any style information for this XML file.

What I want is:

```
<root>
  <job>
    <job_id>109504</job_id>
    <job_description>
      Requirements: 
      1. Be polite. 
      2. 20+ years old.
    </job_description>
  </job>
</root>
```

`<br/>` works, but it looks like this:

```
<root>
  <job>
    <job_id>109504</job_id>
    <job_description>
      Requirements: 
      <br/>
      1. Be polite. 
      <br/>
      2. 20+ years old.
      <br/>
    </job_description>
  </job>
</root>
```

If it is a lot of line breaks in job descriptions it is becoming unreadable.
So I don't want `<br/>` tag to be displayed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[mcve]". Please don't use links to images to display information that is necessary to your question. Instead copy/paste the minimal essential information into your question, formatting it appropriately. That helps us help you, and it helps those in the future. Links rot then break and when that happens your question will make no sense. Show us an example of `job_description` with and without breaks, and what you expect both to look like and what your generated XML looks like.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks a lot :) Updated question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your XML tree to be rendered in a specific way (e.g. with the  line-breaks), not depending on the browser's default XML rendering model (which can vary across the browsers), you better do it yourself by explicitly converting your results to HTML.

For example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

result_XML = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new do |xml|
  xml.root {
    xml.job {
      xml.job_id            1
      xml.job_description   %{ 
               my job
               another line
               one more line
      }
    }   
  }
end
result_HTML = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new do |doc|
  doc.html {
    doc.head {
      doc.script(:src => 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js')
    }
    doc.body(:onload => 'some_func();') {
      doc.pre(:class => "prettyprint lang-xml") {
        doc.text result_XML.to_xml
      }
    }
  }
end

File.open("result.html", 'w') { |f| f.write(result_HTML.to_html) }
```

Alternatively, if you want to still have .xml as the primary output, you may add an XSTL stylesheet to it:

```
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xml2html.xsl" ?>
```

which will make the browser transform it into the HTML document on the fly.

(Note ! "xml2html.xsl" is just a dummy name, you will need to find (or write) a real "generic XML tree to HTML" stylesheet and refer to it instead if you want this to work).